# GWT: Making a column of custom cells

Tags: java, gwt

I'm having trouble understanding how to build columns in GWT. Let's say I have an `ArrayList` of `Book`s and want to list them in a `CellTable`. A special requirement is that each `Book` has an `ArrayList` of `Page`s and I want to build my own HTML code based on the `Page` list.

The [tutorial on custom cells](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html) explains how to make a cell that is fed a `String` and then returns a `String`. However, I want to feed it an `Book` and then get a `String` (by working on the `ArrayList<Page>` of the `Book`). For that purpose, I pretty much copied the sample code for the cell, except that I replaced `String` by `Book`.

I can't figure out how to use this cell to add a column to my `CellTable`. Using a `TextColumn` will take the HTML code the cell's `render` method generates and escape it. My last attempt was to build a `Column<PagesCell, String>`, but the constructor of `Column` wants an object that implements `Cell<String>` while mine implements `Cell<Book>`. What am I doing wrong? Most probably, I have some fundamental misconception on how cells and columns work in GWT. Below, you can see the code I had in mind, but which didn't work.

```java
Cell<Book> pagesCell = new PagesCell();
Column<Book, String> pagesColumn = new Column<Book, String>(pagesCell) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(Book book) {
        PagesCell pagesCell = new PagesCell();
        SafeHtmlBuilder safeHtmlBuilder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        pagesCell.render(null, book, safeHtmlBuilder);
        return safeHtmlBuilder.toSafeHtml().asString();
    }
};
```

This code yields the error

> Column (com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell) in Column cannot be applied to (com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell)

Comment: Did you try `cellTable.addColumn(pagesColumn);` ?

Comment: I hadn't had the chance as I fail to even declare the ```pagesColumn```. I added the error IntelliJ shows in my question.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a cell to the column constructor. After that, there is no need to initialize another cell object in the getValue() method.

You need to create a new Cell by extending [SafeHtmlCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SafeHtmlCell.html), and pass a string that represents HTML you want to render. Then in your column:

```
Column<Book, SafeHtml> pagesColumn = new Column<Book, SafeHtml>(new PagesCell()) {
    @Override
    public SafeHtml getValue(Book book) {
        SafeHtmlBuilder safeHtmlBuilder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
        // create your HTML here - not in the cell, using your Book object
        return safeHtmlBuilder.toSafeHtml();
    }
};
```